# How to validate a change in a cell and determine whether that change should be comited?

Tags: javascript, validation, error-handling, slickgrid

I have something like so:

```
 CELL #0      CELL #1
------------------------
|start_date | end_date |
|----------------------|
|1/1/2012   |1/1/2013  |  ROW#0
|----------------------|
```

I would like to assert that if the user clicks on (Row0,Cell0) and tries to change the start date, then the start date has to be less than the end date else the changes are not put through. Is this possible?

Currently when creating the columns, I add a 'validator' property and pass in the function below

```
startDateValidator(value){ 
   /* value is new value, need to reference the end_date to make sure
      that value < end_date but not possible in this column validator */
}
```

but as the comment points out, we are given the new value but no reference to the old data-item. Is there a way to get around this? I can change the source, but would want to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do it on the `onCellChange` event of the grid, I stripped up some code from a previous implementation I have so don't be too hard on me if it doesn't work first time... Assuming the ID of both your dates are `start_date` and `end_date`, then here is a working concept:

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function(e,args) {
    // do a proper validation of date
    if (args.item.start_date < args.item.end_date) {
        // post/save result to DB and re-render the grid
        $.post('yourAjaxFile.php?action=update', args.item, function(ServerResponseUpt) {   
            // success, update the datagrid view on screen
            grid.updateRow(args.row);
            grid.updateRowCount();
            grid.render();
        });
    }else {
        // invalid, undo the changes from grid, this will put back orginal value
        var command = commandUndoQueue.pop();
        if (command && Slick.GlobalEditorLock.cancelCurrentEdit()) {
            command.undo();
            grid.gotoCell(command.row, command.cell, false);
        }                     
    }                         
});
```

Please note that the dates validation is obviously incorrect here, though the main answer is more focused on how to achieve the rest of the event

Comment: Nice looks good, will test it out today, what is `commandUndoQueue` is this something internal to your code?

Comment: The undo is part of SlickGrid you can find it from another example, I actually edited my code on the undo command, take a look at the SlickGrid example: http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3b-editing-with-undo.html

Comment: and don't forget that the date check I've put here is NOT the proper way to verify a date difference... but that's another subject...for that you could check maybe this: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/datedifference.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnBeforeEdit` instead of `onCellChange`

```
grid.onBeforeEditCell.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    //returning true will update the cell and returning false will not update it
}
```